# Does Flutter support obfuscation of appbundle?

Tags: flutter, obfuscation

[The docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate) saying that

> The following build targets support the obfuscation process described on this page:
>
> - aar
> - apk
> - appbundle
> - ios
> - ...

However, if you run `flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/out` there will be no symbols file in the `/out` directory. In my case it is `c://out` if I would be using `flutter build apk --obfuscate ...`

So it is not clear whether symbols file should and will be generated in case of `appbundle`?

Nevertheless, when using flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/out I do not get any errors.